# Scale angular page onResize

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, resize

I want to resize the content of the page in a way that I can view all components in the page without overflow. I found this example https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/VvRoWy and I adapted the code for an angular way. The javascript of this codepen is

```
var $el = $("#very-specific-design");
var elHeight = $el.outerHeight();
var elWidth = $el.outerWidth();

var $wrapper = $("#scaleable-wrapper");

$wrapper.resizable({
  resize: doResize
});

function doResize(event, ui) {
  
  var scale, origin;
    
  scale = Math.min(
    ui.size.width / elWidth,    
    ui.size.height / elHeight
  );
  
  $el.css({
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%) " + "scale(" + scale + ")"
  });
  
}

var starterData = { 
  size: {
    width: $wrapper.width(),
    height: $wrapper.height()
  }
}
doResize(null, starterData);
```

And my angular component I wrote this

```
onResize(event){
        event.target.innerWidth; // window width

        var scale, origin;
    
        scale = Math.min(
            event.target.innerWidth / this.elWidth,    
            event.target.innerHeight / this.elHeight
        );
        

        this.renderer.setStyle(this.vsd.nativeElement, 'transform', "translate(-50%, -50%) scale("+scale+")");
    }
```

This is the html part

```
<div class="div-content">
        <div #scaleablewrapper class="scaleable-wrapper" id="scaleable-wrapper">
            <div #veryspecificdesign class="very-specific-design" id="very-specific-design">
                <div class="div-container">
                    <h3>Hello1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="div-container">
                    <h3>Hello2</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="div-container">
                    <h3>Hello3</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="div-container">
                    <h3>Hello4</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It's working like the example but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I need the opposite. Bigger is the screen, smaller should be the content. Currently is, bigger is the screen, bigger is also the content. Is it possibile do that? The important thing is not scroll the page to show the components and show everything in the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to inverse your scale

```
scale = 1 / Math.min(
            event.target.innerWidth / this.elWidth,    
            event.target.innerHeight / this.elHeight
        );
```